# Rails 4 Business Logic, Authorization - Updating Prices based on Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, business-logic, role-base-authorization

I have a super basic ecommerce app with a User model authenticated with Omniauth, Product model with name and price, and ShoppingCart and ShoppingCartItem models (utilizing the `acts_as_shopping_cart` gem).

My issue is when I have a user authenticate through an Omniauth provider, I want to provide discounts based on who they authenticate with.

Let's say they sign in with facebook - then I want to provide a 20% discount for them. I'm not sure how to go about this actually - I think I want to write this business logic in my Product and ShoppingCartItem models, setting something like

```
def self.price 
  if current_user.provider == 'facebook'
    super * 0.8 
  else
    super
end
```

but I can't access `current_user` within the models because it is set by the session.

Should I do it in the controller where I have access to current_user? Then I'd have to open the Product and ShoppingCartItem classes within the controllers to override their price methods which all feels wrong and frankly I don't know if it will even work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my strategy a bit. I decided to create a method to override the `total` method on my shoppingcart instance. I didn't want to change the prices, I just applied the discount to the total like you would see at the checkout view.

I created an instance method in the model `shopping_cart.rb` like so:

```
def discount(user)
  if user && user.provider == 'facebook'
    def total
      super * 0.8
    end
  else
    def total
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Then I can call this method in the controller and pass in `current_user` there.

`shopping_carts_controller.rb`

```
def show
  @shopping_cart.discount(current_user)
end
```

And in the view I just have `@shopping_cart.total` where the `total` method is overriden based on the user's oauth provider!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it helps

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter do |obj|
     User.current_user = User.find(obj.session[:user]) unless obj.session[:user].nil?

   end
end`

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :current_user
end`

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Just one question - isn't `attr_accessor` a deprecated thing since Rails 4 with strong params? Or are you doing some kind of trickery here?

Comment: @tony- sorry it's my bad.it should be `cattr_accessor: current_user`

Comment: Interesting - could you explain what `cattr_accessor` is I've never seen it before? I actually found my own solution I'll go ahead and post it :)